# Multiple conditions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

**Is there any way to test for multiple conditions in Java in a short way?**

Let's use the following example:

```
if(height == 1 && width == 3 && visible && running && users<3)
doThis();
```

This is a rather short test, but what if there's more? I'm aware of that nested `if(test)` can help with the structure, but also this becomes hard to follow after some 10 tests. Imagine also the test varies in the code, so no standardised method can be called. Is the stated way the only decent possibility?

Comment: I can suggest implementing a Decision Table, which will make your code more readable (at least).

Comment: Yes unfortunately , if there's more you need to add more , as simple as that

Comment: Is the question about just this one `if`, or do you have a series of those `if`s will all (or many) combinations of those conditions?

Comment: `&&` operator has Associativity Left --> Right. So, if condition on left is `false` then condition on right of it is not executed.

Comment: @M.S. that's not what the question is about. It's about how to deal with long if statements

Comment: @tobias_k Not sure what you mean, but the question is general and came up when solving some Euler problems. There I could use a 'for' loop and compare the created 'Array' to one containing only 'true', but that's (pretty much) only possible when the tests use the same type. Imagine a test sequence of 30+ tests.

Comment: @JindraHelcl I am helping him with assiciativity in operators, it will benifit compiler too.

Comment: You may try to implement a class that would do some handling of boolean expressions, but I don't think it'll imporve the readability of the code. Instead, you may try to give a name to some combinations of boolean expressions, for example `boolean big = (height >= 10 && width >= 10);` and then use them in the if statements, like `if (big && expensive) doThis();`

Comment: I dont think there's shorter way. You have to write 10 conditions if all of them needs to be judged.

Comment: @JindraHelcl that makes more statements. Not an answer.

Comment: Why not chunk groups of conditional checks into functions? if (Condition1Passed() && Condition2Passed()), where Condition1Passed() is a subset of checks and Condition2Passed() is the next subset and so on?

Comment: @M.S. that's why i put it in the comments. More statements is better than less, if the code becomes better to read.

Comment: Once you write `if(...)` with 10 conditions. Then i would suggest you to thing again about your problem decomposition. Might be a flaw in design.

Comment: Ok. Seems as there are pretty many approaches to this problem. I have to look into them all. The general answer seems to be: No, there is no definitive easier way, but the most suitable structuring differ per situation.